# Overloading [] operator in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, operator-overloading

Im trying to overload the [] operator in c++ so that I can assign / get values from my data structure like a dictionary is used in c#:

Array["myString"] = etc.

Is this possible in c++?

I attempted to overload the operator but it doesnt seem to work,

```
Record& MyDictionary::operator[] (string& _Key)
{
for (int i = 0; i < used; ++i)
{
    if (Records[i].Key == _Key)
    {
        return Records[i]; 
    }
}
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  What are `Records`, `Records[i]`, `Key`, and `used`?  Have you considered just using `std::map`, which provides `SortedDictionary`-like functionality, or `std::unordered_map` (if your implementation provides it), which provides `Dictionary`-like functionality?

Comment: If you're going to write an operator like this, it's good practice to add const to the argument: `Record& MyDictionary::operator[] (const string& _Key)`.

Comment: In addition to Ted's comment, without the const qualifier it would be illegal to do the following: `Array["myString"];` because you cannot reference temporary objects. Not sure if I explained that correctly, I just learned it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is on the right track - you've got the right function signature - but your logic is a bit flawed.  In particular, suppose that you go through this loop without finding the key you're looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < used; ++i)
{
    if (Records[i].Key == _Key)
    {
        return Records[i]; 
    }
}
```

If this happens, your function doesn't return a value, which leads to undefined behavior.  Since it's returning a reference, this is probably going to cause a nasty crash the second that you try using the reference.

To fix this, you'll need to add some behavior to ensure that you don't fall off of the end of the function.  One option would be to add the key to the table, then to return a reference to that new table entry.  This is the behavior of the STL `std::map` class's `operator[]` function.  Another would be to throw an exception saying that the key wasn't there, which does have the drawback of being a bit counterintuitive.

On a totally unrelated note, I should point out that technically speaking, you should not name the parameter to this function `_Key`.  The C++ standard says that any identifier name that starts with two underscores (i.e. `__myFunction`), or a single underscore followed by a capital letter (as in your `_Key` example) is reserved by the implementation for whatever purposes they might deem necessary.  They could `#define` the identifier to something nonsensical, or have it map to some compiler intrinsic.  This could potentially cause your program to stop compiling if you move from one platform to another.  To fix this, either make the `K` lower-case (`_key`), or remove the underscore entirely (`Key`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt seem to work though, atleast intellisense doesn't pick up on it. If I type do MyDictionary["myString"] it says it must be a int or enum type. Do I need to use const somehow?

Comment: Please provide the problematic code. `MyDictionary["myString"]` seems to confuse type and instance.

Comment: myDictionary = MyDictionary::Instance(); (singleton pattern) Record test = myDictionary["test"]-> (nothing comes up) Error says "test" must be integer or enum type . However this works, Record test = myDictionary->operator[]("test");

Comment: @Sean- What is `myDictionary?`  If it's a pointer, then the problem would be that writing `myDictionary["test"]` won't call the overloaded `[]` operator; instead it will try to index into an array whose first element is pointed at by `myDictionary` and whose index is the string `"test"`, hence the error.  If it is a pointer, then you'll have to write `(*myDictionary)["test"]` to call `operator[]`.

Comment: Gotcha. That works, thanks. Im using singleton for the instance of MyDictionary. Should I not be returning a pointer?

Comment: @Sean- Judgment call.  If it's a singleton, then returning by reference might be better off so that you can't accidentally use a NULL pointer.  It also will make it possible to directly apply `operator[]`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, one of the problems with `operator[](const Key& key)` is that, as templatetypedef states, in order to return a reference it needs to be non-const.

To have a const accessor, you need a method that can return a fail case value. In STL this is done through using `find()` and the use of iterators and having `end()` indicate a fail.

An alternative is to return a pointer, with a null indicating a fail. This is probably justified where the default constructed Record is meaningless. This can be also be done with the array operator:

```
Record* MyDictionary::operator[] (const string& keyToFind) const
{ 

    for (int i = 0; i < used; ++i)
    {
        if (Records[i].Key == keyToFind)
        {
            return &Records[i]; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is certainly a view that `operator[]` should return a reference. In that case, you'd most likely implement `find()` as well and implement `operator[]` in terms of it.

To implement find() you need to define an iterator type. The convenient type will depend in implementation. For example, if Records[] is a plain old array:

```
typedef Record* iterator;
typedef const Record* const_iterator;
const_iterator MyDictionary::end()const
{
    return Records + used;
}
const_iterator MyDictionary::begin() const
{
    return Records;
}
const_iterator MyDictionary::find(const string& keyToFind) const
{ 
    for (iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->Key == keyToFind)
        {
            return it; 
        }
    }
    return end();
}
```

Comment: Anywhere I can find documentation on how to implement find() and end() myself?